# To store the key in a same directory and validate it at the start up of the application

Tags: c#

I have 2 Windows application forms. In the first form I have a button and in the second form a button and a textbox.

When I click on the button in the first form the program should check if the product is already activated or not. If it's activated, then it should continue with `form1`, otherwise it should call `form2` asking to input the product key.

Once the product key is inputted into `form2` the program should validate it and store it in a text file in the same directory.

When I run the program the next time, after clicking on the button in `form1`, it should not ask to activate it again.

I have the below code, but I am not getting this full functionality. Please help me with this and also please help with exception while reading or writing the text file.

```
// FIRST FORM

private void fixButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextReader tr = new StreamReader("Product-Key.txt");

    if ( (tr.ToString() == "TGR2W2") || (tr.ToString() == "8DTT9M") )
    {
        MessageBox.Show ( "product is already activated ");
    }
    else 
    {
        Form2 secondForm = new Form2();
        secondForm.Show();
    }
}
```

// ACTIVATION BUTTON IN SECOND FORM

```
private void activateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if ((productkeyTextBox.Text == "TGR2W2") || (productkeyTextBox.Text == "8DTT9M") )
    {
        // to store the inputted product key in a tex file of the same directory
        keyStore ((productkeyTextbOX.Text).ToString());
        this.Close();

        MessageBox.Show(" The product has been succesfully activated");
        // NEED HELP HERE IN LOADING THE FORM 1 BACK AFTER STORING THE PRODUCT KEY 
     }
     else
     {
         MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid 16 digit product key!!");
     }
}

public void keyStore(string key)
{
    try
    {
        // create a writer and open the file
        TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("Product-Key.txt");

        // write a line of text to the file
        tw.WriteLine(key);

        // close the stream
        tw.Close();
    }
    catch (IOException)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not getting this full functionality", and exactly what is the exception you are getting?

Comment: By the way, you can simplify a lot of the file I/O you are doing... you can probably get away with **File.ReadAllText("Product-Key.txt")** to read the key from the file and **File.WriteAllText("Product-Key.txt",productkeyTextbOX.Text)** to write the key to the file.

Comment: One more thing... in your **fixButton_Click** method you attempt to open a stream for a file which may not yet exist, and you do not have it wrapped in a try/catch. Your code as shown will throw an unhandled exception if the user clicks the button and the file does not yet exist.